Парсинг первого результата на запрос в яндекс
У меня есть csv файл с запросами в яндекс. Никак не могу спарсить первую ссылку результата яндекса. Использую selenium.
def get_first_yandex_link(query):
try:
    encoded_query = quote_plus(query)
    search_url = f"https://yandex.ru/search/?text={encoded_query}&search_source=dzen_desktop_safe&lr=213"

    driver.get(search_url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    first_result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.serp-item a.link')))

    first_link = first_result.get_attribute('href')
    return first_link
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка при поиске: {e}")
    return None

Выдает такую ошибку:Ошибка при поиске: Message:
Stacktrace:

GetHandleVerifier [0x007F8283+26163]  (No symbol) [0x00789D34]    (No
symbol) [0x006824C3]  (No symbol) [0x006C7453]    (No symbol)
[0x006C762B]  (No symbol) [0x00706B62]    (No symbol) [0x006EAD04]    (No
symbol) [0x00704661]  (No symbol) [0x006EAA56]    (No symbol)
[0x006BBE89]  (No symbol) [0x006BC8CD]    GetHandleVerifier
[0x00ACCF73+2994979]  GetHandleVerifier [0x00B217E9+3341209]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00887B5F+614159]   GetHandleVerifier
[0x0088F1EC+644508]   (No symbol) [0x0079286D]    (No symbol)
[0x0078F768]  (No symbol) [0x0078F905]    (No symbol) [0x00781C86]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75B67BA9+25]     RtlInitializeExceptionChain
[0x7753C10B+107]  RtlClearBits [0x7753C08F+191]

